# App Engine Java API pageSize

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

Why has google decided to ignore `pageSize` parameter and why the overall size of the collected items differs when using different page size? Here is an example:

```
Appsactivity.Activities.List  request = service.activities().list()
    .setDriveAncestorId(ancestorId)
    .setGroupingStrategy("driveUi") 
    .setSource("drive.google.com")
    .setUserId("me")
    .setPageSize(pageSize);

List<Activity> list = new LinkedList<>();
ListActivitiesResponse response = null;

do {
   response = request.execute();
   List<Activity> fetched = response.getActivities();
   System.out.println("page items: " + fetched.size());

   list.addAll(fetched);
   request.setPageToken(response.getNextPageToken());

} while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

System.out.println("all items: " + list.size())
```

When I set `pageSize` to 100, I will get 720 items (64, 71, 60, 60, 76, 92, 87, 74, 62, 56, 18), however when I set `pageSize` to 5 the result set contains 810 items. Am I missing something or it's an API bug?

**EDIT**

I've just checked singleEvents counts by using event time as key. Few events were duplicated, however the significant difference between events count is still present, when using different pageSize.

Another question like this [google-api-java-client-pagesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739879/google-api-java-client-pagesize)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is a **bug** according to the following links:

Result set can probably contain **duplicates** in some cases 
[is-paging-broken-in-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679190/is-paging-broken-in-drive)

The following link contains explanation of the page size **oscilation**.
[drive-api-search-results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430824/drive-api-search-results)